# The phone return empty when I want to get the phone number

Tags: android, android-permissions

Some phones return null when I want to get the phone number. In other phones I get the phone number.
This happens when Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My phone number is "Unkow". Not writed there the phone number.

Why is this happening?How can I get a phone number ?

The code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect to get phone number of Android device.It will return you number.But sometimes it gives you null because that devices Service provider has not given permission to do that.

Means It works like : Android devices Request SIM card/Service provider for card info with phone number. And In response, Some provider have returned phone number of user and some has refused to do so.

Comment: So what can I do ? There is another way ?

Comment: No, You can't do anything in this case. Because Device's GSM provider has refused to reveal phone number info.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what specifically you're asking for? If you're saying that it happens when in your phone's settings, under About Phone->Status->My phone number, it says "Unknown", then unfortunately that's not a programming question and not a question for here. Is that the case?

Comment: P.S. I would have asked that as a comment to him but unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet for that.

Comment: I wonder why it does not take that number and is there another way ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want `mPhoneNumber` to be filled with "Unknown" in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get device phone number in any ways. It depends on the service provider, some may allow access and some may not since it is completely dependent on the network access privileges. But in rare case you would get the phone number once the user has configured their own mobile number with the SIM card provider. The other way to do this by fetching the number from Facebook that too the user should have registered their mobile number, whereas the earlier versions of whatsapp provides this feature, but it is not compatible with the newer ones.

Note: It works with few custom phones which provides the access.(i.e., phones synced with only particular network providers)